# Compare with Clipboard

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I'm missing the `Compare With -> Clipboard` option, present in `Eclipse 3.2` and superior.
This feature is essential to compare blocks of code.

Why is it not present in `Aptana Studio 3`?

Will it be added or can I add with some configuration or `plugin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature can be added to plugin with [AnyEdit tools plugin for Eclipse](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/).